# Simplifying Rolling Correlation Output in Pandas into a Single Index DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have a reasonably sized DataFrame of time-series data and I would like to have rolling pairwise correlation data in a reasonable format.

Pandas has a very interesting 'rolling' feature that does the correct calculations

```
dfCorrelations = dfReturns.rolling(correlation_window).corr()
```

but the output time series of correlation grids is inconvenient for my later use (sample output for a subset on a given date shown).

[image]

Is there a way to do the same calculation, but get the output in a simple time-series DataFrame with only the *unique*, non-diagonal correlations?  Say with an column index that looks something like

```
['III LN x ABN NA', 'III LN x AGN NA', 'III LN x AGS BB', 'ABN NA x AGN NA', 'ABN NA x AGS BB', ...]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

# Create sample dataset.
idx = pd.MultiIndex(
    levels=[[u'2017-1-1', u'2017-1-2'], [u'A', u'B', u'C']],
    labels=[[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]],
    names=[u'date', u'ticker'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), index=idx, columns=list('ABC'))
for tup in zip(range(6), range(3) * 2):
    df.iloc[tup] = 1

>>> df
                        A         B         C
date     ticker                              
2017-1-1 A       1.000000  0.440276 -1.087536
         B      -0.809949  1.000000 -0.548897
         C       0.922866 -0.788699  1.000000
2017-1-2 A       1.000000 -0.106493  0.034319
         B       0.080990  1.000000  0.218323
         C       0.051651 -0.680358  1.000000

# Unstack and remove duplicates.
tickers = df.columns.tolist()
df = df.unstack().sort_index(axis=1)
pairs = df.columns.get_values().tolist()
df.columns = ["{0} vs. {1}".format(*pair) for pair in pairs]
mask = [n for n, pair in enumerate(pairs) if pair in list(combinations(tickers, 2))]
df = df.iloc[:, mask]
>>> df
           A vs. B   A vs. C   B vs. C
date                                  
2017-1-1 -0.809949  0.922866 -0.788699
2017-1-2  0.080990  0.051651 -0.680358
```

Comment: Thanks!  A very efficient solution.

Comment: Hi @Alexander, I'd love that solution to work for me, but I cannot make it work:
`pairs = df.columns.get_values().tolist()` throws an error, saying `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'get_values'`. I assume that might have something to do with Pandas-Version (I'm using 1.0.5). I tried `get_level_values(0)`, but then I'm failing on the next step:
`["{0} vs. {1}".format(*pair) for pair in pairs]` with `IndexError: tuple index out of range`
Would you (or someone else) mind explaining what happens there?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The preceding line `df.unstack().sort_index(axis=1)` turns the multiindex (date and ticker) into a regular index (date only).

Comment: Thanks @Alexander for the prompt reply! Indeed I got the example working on `Python 3.5`and `pandas=0.20`, but _not_ under `Python 3.7.7`and `pandas=1.0.5`. The `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'get_values'`  shows in the Python 3.5/Pandas 1.0.5 setup. Somewhere in between something must have changed...

Comment: As of `pandas>=1`, `.get_values()`is deprecated. In order to make @Alexander 's example work in that case, change `pairs = df.columns.get_values().tolist()` to `pairs = df.columns.to_numpy().tolist()`.